# Razor/Javascript, best practice

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

im pretty new to MVC-razor and is left with a code thats abit confusing to me.

I have a model in my view and from that model i create a list.

```
      @For Each Item in Model
                  @<li><a href="#" data-id="ItemOne">Click Me</a></li>
```

I then have a javascript that makes the bindning;

```
$("a[data-id]").click(function(e)
{
    $( "#PopUp" ).dialog({resizable: false, width:800, height: 400, title: ""  });
});
```

And populate this static window;

```
<div id="PopUp" title="PopUp">

 <h1>MyPopUp<H1>

</div>
```

All this code is in one View

I now want to populate the window with some of my Models-item-data (IE, the item i click on gives me a popup with that items data) and i have come to a locked mindset, my idea was to have some kind of open razor variable with that model data, then loop through the  items to create equal amounts of PoP-Up-window with a given identifier, when the javascript is called i just use the variable there. But this just feel stupid. Is there any easy (better looking)way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AJAX. Basically you could have a real anchor to a controller action that will return a partial view. And then when this anchor is clicked send an AJAX request to this action and update the DOM.

I guess that an example might be worth it:

```
@For Each Item in Model
    @<li>@Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "SomeAction", "SomeControllerName", New With { Key .id = item.Id }, New With { Key .class = "popup" })</li>
```

and then you could unobtrusively AJAXify this anchor:

```
$('a.popup').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href, 
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#PopUp').html(result).dialog({
                resizable: false, 
                width: 800, 
                height: 400, 
                title: ''
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

and then of course you will have a corresponding controller action that will render the partial:

```
Function SomeAction(ByVal id as Integer)
    Dim model = ... get your model from somewhere using the id
    Return PartialView(model)
End Function
```

Comment: And as always you saved my day Darin. Thanks! :)